# Heatmap Generation Library for PHP

Tags: php, heatmap, image-generation

I want to generate heatmap images as overlay for Google Maps. I am searching for a PHP library which can take multiple dimensions into account when generating the image. Let's say i have 2 dimensions: density and quality. How could a heatmap be generated from this input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fusionTable](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html), refer to [here](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/) for some sample PHP code.

Comment: I am not sure if that will help me. I do not see any reference to heatmaps.

Comment: Here is an example[link]http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#FusionTablesHeatmaps) using fusionTable with heatmap. You can use the fusionTable API to genereate heatmap.

Comment: Thank you, i had to change explicitly to the english version of the documentation to find it. Looks useful, but i'll have to look into it to see if it's sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to generate heatmap layers over google maps you probably want to check out [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) too, it's licensed under the MIT license. It works with the HTML5 Canvas element and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but if someone stumbles upon it you might want to check out Google's chart offerings: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart