# Google Map: how to label a large number of addresses

Tags: google-maps

I want to label around 300K addresses according to their longitudes and latitudes on the google map. By labeling, I mean put an indication sign on the map.

Are there any methods to realize it? Thank you.

Best,
Leon

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'label'

Comment: If problem is in handling a large amount of markers - take a look at [Showing many markers in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413122/showing-many-markers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have full, proper addresses and you want to geocode them (find lat/lngs) then consider using Google Fusion Tables - its like a spreadsheet to which you can define a location field.

Then, you can tell Google Fusion Tables to geocode those addresses for you and it fills in the lat/lng location, and creates a kml file from this with "infoboxes" which you can define.

The geocoding process should be seen as one-off operation, and may take somewhere between many minutes and many hours to do this work.

Comment: You just have to watch. FT generally has a limit of 100k points on a map. A single table can contain more rows. but only the first 100k points will be put on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [geocoding api](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)